# Can I block a form submit action after first click

Tags: html, post, web

On a webpage, is it safe to block a submit action after user clicked it once (to avoid double posting) or is there a risk that I now block my user, in case of no/bad connectivity, post not reaching the server etc..

So in other words, can I trust that my post request always reaches the server and back to the user?

Comment: Make a success response from server, if you get success then only block submit, if you want to block.

Comment: onSubmit event of form disable submit button if you are redirecting to other page

Answer (score 1):

It is ok to disable button on Submit... but please make sure that you execute SUBMIT script after you have disabled it...

p.s. Common behavior is that submit button does not proceed to submit after you disabled it, you should do it manually.

To encounter no/bad connectivity, you can set javaScript timer that will return submit button to its normal state after some time, so user can click it again

Comment: My thoughts were in these lines as well, with a timeout that re-enable the button, but is it really needed, can a scenario like that happen? And is there a way that I can recreate that scenario in my browser? (with network throttling or similar)

Comment: it happens... and in this case browser will throw an error... which is ok for most of the cases. do you really need it or not, depends on requirements...
If you really care about Data Integrity, you can execute "check connectivity" script to make sure connection is ok and then submit form...

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should send a server call and disable the submit button and wait for the response to comeback and if status is failed enable submit button otherwise do nothing and process the response as you need it

i think you are using javascript for making a server call if yes then it's very easy to pass a callback and listen for the response